# PHPUnit Test failing when internal Array is set

Tags: testing, phpunit

have numerous tests working, but my actual test of some objects is failing and I am not sure why.  When I step through the code in a simple test, I can see that what I am trying to test is defined, but PHPUnit fails the testing.

I have small code samples edited below to try to illustrate the issue without too much noise.

Very simple subset of a class definition.

```
class UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE extends UTIL_MESSAGE_DATA
{
    function __construct($CategoryNo = NULL, $CategoryName = NULL)
    {
        $this->DeclareClassFields_();

        $this->CategoryName = $CategoryName;
        $this->CategoryNo   = $CategoryNo;
    }

    private function DeclareClassFields_()
    {
        $this->Fields['CategoryNo']             = new UTIL_ICAP_FIELD('CCL', 6, 'Category', 8);
        $this->Fields['SubCategoryNo']          = new UTIL_ICAP_FIELD('SCC', 6, 'Sub-Category', 12);
        $this->Fields['SubSubCategoryNo']       = new UTIL_ICAP_FIELD('SSC', 6, 'Sub-Sub-Category', 12);
    }
}
```

Normal code in Netbeans debugger to see this works.

```
$Category = new UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE();
```

Dump contents for comparison for the PHPUnit test samples to follow.

```
var_dump($Category);

class UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE#1 (4) {
  public $TheMessage_ =>
  class MESSAGE_DATA#2 (0) {
  }
```

This is OK.  Expected and works, as the class InstanceOf can be tested and passes correctly.

Internally, there is a list of fields maintained in an array, which is an array of class objects, that uses magic methods for get/set values, etc...  Is the Array initialized?

```
var_dump($Category->Fields);

array(3) {
    'CategoryNo' =>
        class UTIL_ICAP_FIELD#3 (14) {
            public $FieldCode =>
                string(3) "CCL"
            public $FieldLength =>
                int(6)
            public $FieldTitle =>
                string(8) "Category"
        }
    'SubCategoryNo' =>
        class UTIL_ICAP_FIELD#4 (14) {
            public $FieldCode =>
                string(3) "SCC"
            public $FieldLength =>
                int(6)
            public $FieldTitle =>
                string(12) "Sub-Category"
        }
    'SubSubCategoryNo' =>
        class UTIL_ICAP_FIELD#5 (14) {
            public $FieldCode =>
                string(3) "SSC"
            public $FieldLength =>
                int(6)
            public $FieldTitle =>
                string(16) "Sub-Sub-Category"
        }
    }
```

Array is initialized as expected.
Check that the Array exists and the individual items may be accessed.

```
if (array_key_exists('CategoryNo', $Category->Fields))
    echo 'Array Key Exists';

    Array Key Exists

if( $Category->Fields['CategoryNo'] instanceof UTIL_ICAP_FIELD )
    echo 'Yes';

Yes
```

All is reporting as expected.

PHPUnit Test partial:

```
class TEST_UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
    }

    public function testObjectCreation()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $this->assertInstanceOf('UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE', $CategoryInfo);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('UTIL_DATA_STRUCTURE', $CategoryInfo);
    }

    public function testConstructFieldOrder()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE(1500, 'Category Name');
        $this->assertEquals(1500, $CategoryInfo->CategoryNo);
        $this->assertEquals('Category Name', $CategoryInfo->CategoryName);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function testConstructDefaults()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $this->assertNull($CategoryInfo->CategoryNo);
        $this->assertNull($CategoryInfo->CategoryName);
    }
```

These tests pass as expected.  However, given the dumps of information above, the following 2 tests fail, even though the test run and var_dump show that the values are initialized and present as expected.

```
    public function testFieldsCreated()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('CategoryNo', $CategoryInfo->Fields);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('SubCategoryNo', $CategoryInfo->Fields);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('SubSubCategoryNo', $CategoryInfo->Fields);
    }
```

Errors Created:

```
1) TEST_UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE::testFieldsCreated
Failed asserting that an array has the key 'CategoryNo'.
```

Next Test

```
    public function testICAPFieldTypes()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $this->assertInstanceOf('UTIL_ICAP_FIELD', $CategoryInfo->Fields['CategoryNo']);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('UTIL_ICAP_FIELD', $CategoryInfo->Fields['SubCategoryNo']);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('UTIL_ICAP_FIELD', $CategoryInfo->Fields['SubSubCategoryNo']);
    }
```

Errors Created:

```
2) TEST_UTIL_CATEGORY_SCOPE::testICAPFieldTypes
Failed asserting that null is an instance of class "UTIL_ICAP_FIELD".
```

I am not sure how to continue as this causes errors when I can see that the objects are created, the arrays populated as I would expect.  I have to mark these tests as Incomplete for now, to allow our test suite to continue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are the error message you are getting? Are those classes namespaced by any chance?

Comment: No. We are testing with PHP 5.3.17 and PHPUnit 3.6.10, but our release code is actually running on PHP 5.2.17, so we do not have name spaces.  I updated the description to include the errors generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, after some deep inspection of the class.  The array I was attempting to access was defined as PROTECTED, so the PHPUnit Test Framework could not access the value.

There is two solutions to get around this.

1. Declare the array as PUBLIC to make it accessible.
2. Use Reflection in the Tests to make it accessible for the tests only.

Option 2 is our preferred solution, but for the immediate needs of the project, and the time for the other changes, Option 1 (PUBLIC) was used temporarily.

Thanks to those who helped to try to solve my issue.